# Kernel update for Ubuntu 12.04 with Linux 3.11.0-15-generic is failing

Tags: kernel

How to update to Linux 3.11.0-15-generic on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Below errors are seen while performing the upgrade. 'Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.11.0.15-generic'

Comment: This question is specific to an end of life Ubuntu release - 12.04. These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 12.04 has passed end of life (unless you have (paid for) extended security maintenance, that you are an Ubuntu Advantage customer). As a regular user you cannot expect to update and upgrade Ubuntu within the version 12.04 LTS.

Please make a fresh installation of a current version! I would suggest that you try the version 16.04 LTS,

- standard Ubuntu
- or one of the community flavours with a light desktop environment, if the computer is getting old (Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu).

Try first (booted from DVD or USB), and install, when you find a version/flavour, that works well. See this link

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I was actually looking for this precise version for one of my setup.